# Extend 2 classes in one class of 'this' in javascript

Tags: javascript, oop, multiple-inheritance

i met the problem, that i do not how extend from the third class.. So i really need the way to call the A class with parameter 'TYPE', extend with C, and be able call getType() with class C. Any solutions?

```js
const TYPE = 'TYPE'

class A {
    constructor(type) {
        this.type = type;
    }
    
    getType() {
        return this.type;
    }
}

class B {
 constructor(id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    
    getId() {
        return this.id;
    }
}

class C extends B {
    constructor(id) {
        super(id);
        
        //Here should be a function that should bind the method from class A
    }
}

const c = new C(1);
console.log(c.getId())
console.log(c.getType())
```

Comment: Why not have `class B extends A`? Or do you really ask about how to inherit from both `A` and `B` in `C`??

Comment: In javascript, when you do `extend` basically you are doing is `prototypical inheritance`. As your base object can have only one prototype, you can not do multiple inheritance. One thing you can do is that your B class can extend A class, so indirectly your C class will be extending both.

Comment: `Object.assign(this, A.prototype)` could go where your comment is.

Comment: @4castle But you can see that A have a parameter TYPE, which i need to put where is a comment, and in the future use the method of class A getType()

Comment: @Bergi inherit A B and C

Comment: JavaScript doesn't support multiple inheritance, so you would have to assign any other properties you want manually.

Comment: @EdwardGizbreht Have a look a mixins then. JS doesn't support multiple prototype inheritance.

Comment: @EdwardGizbreht Why to proceed with incorrect design itself?

Answer (score 0):

```js
const TYPE = 'TYPE'

class A {
    constructor(type) {
        this.type = type;
    }
    
    getType() {
        return this.type;
    }
    
    extend(extendedClassInstance){
      extendedClassInstance.type = this.type;
      extendedClassInstance.getType = this.getType.bind(extendedClassInstance)
    }
}

class B {
 constructor(id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    
    getId() {
        return this.id;
    }
}

class C extends B {
    constructor(id) {
        super(id);
        (new A(TYPE)).extend(this) 
    }
}

const c = new C(1);
console.log(c.getId())
console.log(c.getType())
```

Comment: Don't use `.bind(extendedClassInstance)`.